# d3.behaviour.zoom disable panning on touchscreen when using only one finger

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a force-layout d3 chart and I am using `d3.behaviour.zoom` to enable zooming and panning.

It all works great but because my chart fills the screen on an iPad it becomes impossible to scroll further down the page as my touch just pans the chart.

I want to keep the pinch zoom behaviour on touch devices.

Is it possible to cancel the `touchmove.zoom` event *only* when `d3.event.touches.length === 1`?

This just disables all touch interaction - so the scrolling is fine but I can't zoom the chart any more:

```js
selection.call(zoom)
    .on('touchstart.zoom', null)
    .on('touchmove.zoom', null)
    .on('touchend.zoom', null);
```

I've also tried adding another `touchmove` listener, like this:

```js
selection.call(zoom)
    .on('touchmove', function () {
        if (d3.event.touches.length === 1) {
            d3.event.stopPropagation();
            // i've also tried d3.event.preventDefault() but it doesn't do anything         
        }
    });
```

I don't think I can access the default zoom `touchmove` listener within d3 can I? I was wondering if I could remove the listener on `touchstart` and then rebind it on `touchend` if the user is only using one touch.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need more fine grained control of events than can be achieved using the built in events. Try creating an object that handles standard events and converts them into custom events (based on the rules you choose, such as only 1 touch). You can then listen for these custom events being thrown with the help of the d3 dispatch mechanism.

```
Events = function() {

  // custom event set up using d3 dispatch
  var dispatch = d3.dispatch("drag", "drag2");

  //listen for standard event on containing DOM element
  var events = function (g) {
    //g is the container DOM element

    // register the standard events required
    g.on("touchmove", touchmove)

    return events;
  };

  //function that handles the touchmove standard event
  function touchmove(d,i) {

    //stop the default event going any further
    d3.event.stopPropagation();

    //depending on your conditions choose which custom event you trigger
    if(condition1)
    {
      dispatch.drag.call(d3.event.target, d, i);
    }
    else if(condition2)
    {
      dispatch.drag2.call(d3.event.target, d, i);
    }
  }

  //add events defined in d3 dispatch function to events object and return   
  return d3.rebind(events, dispatch, "on");
}
```

Elsewhere in your code create the events object and listen for its custom events:

```
events = new Events();

//Set the containing element the events object should be registering event listeners to
d3.select(container).call(events);

events.on("drag", function (d, i, position) {
    //do something here
})

events.on("drag2", function (d, i, position) {
    //do something else here
})
```

Comment: Using this technique I'd have to write my own custom `touchmove.zoom` handler to replicate the built- in one, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Are you sure you can't get selection.call(zoom) zoom.on("zoom", function() {... to do what you need to do?

Answer (score 0):

One way without using d3 dispatch is to use the original `touchstart` event listener instead of d3.  Through `event.touches.length`, you can get a count of how many touches detected on the screen.

By adding the listener and having an additional check for when the touch count is 1 in 
`d3.behaviour.zoom`, it prevents panning when one finger is on the graph and will default to normally scrolling the page instead.

```
let touchCount = 0;

// Only necessary to add listener when running on mobile/tablet
// (assuming you already have some detection set up)

if (isMobileSize) {
    document.querySelector('.your-svg').addEventListener('touchstart', (e) => {
        touchCount = e.touches.length;
    });
}


let selection = d3.select('.your-svg');
let zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', () => {

    // When 1 finger, do not zoom
    if (touchCount === 1) {
        d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
        return;
    }

    // Otherwise run zoom/move
    // ... zoom logic goes here....
})

selection.call(zoom)
```